# Why did this jetty connector folder mysteriously appear in my files?

Tags: https, jetty, directory, virus

Today I opened my laptop and navigated to a folder called "work," which I use only to store documents. I noticed that a new subfolder is inside it, called "jetty-0.0.0.0-31415-internal-connector-_internal-connector-any-" that was not there yesterday. I did not create this folder, nor did I install any new software in the last week. The folder contains only another folder called "jsp" which is empty. When I googled "jetty-0.0.0.0-31415-internal-connector-_internal-connector-any-" the only result was from a server belonging to MIT, which also has this folder inside a directory called "work." Where could this have come from? Could it mean I have a virus of some kind? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would be a standard Jetty directory for the temporary folder on a specific webapp for a running Jetty server.

The filename ...

```
jetty-0.0.0.0-31415-internal-connector-_internal-connector-any-
```

tells you ....

- `jetty` - a jetty temporary directory
- `0.0.0.0` - listening on all network interfaces
- `31415` - listening on port 31415
- `internal-connector` - using a custom network connector (quite unusual)
- `_internal-connector` - using context path `/internal-connector`
- `any` - accepting any virtual host provided

Based on the `/internal-connector` and the port `31415` I'd say this is a temporary directory from the MATLAB project.

If you happen to be building MATLAB (or related projects related to MATLAB) these directories might also be coming from the actual testcases of those projects you are building.